# SQL Server 2014 FullText . (dot) problems

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm struggling with fulltext search in SQL Server 2014 on Azure.

I have SKUs with multiple dots inside like `03.9216.14`.

If I search for the whole SKU like this:

```
Contains(CompanyProductionCode, '"*03.9216.14A*"')
```

it returns data, but if I do

```
Contains(CompanyProductionCode, '"*03.9216*"')
```

nothing is returned.

Any idea why and how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fulltext searching is designed for **words** not random collection of characters. Use LIKE or the typical string searching functions.

Comment: You are right, I ended up using Like and it works perfectly. Thanks